# Can't open /etc/nginx/default.conf.tpl: no such file

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, yaml

Currently im making a house from Udemy: Build a Backend REST API with Python & Django - Advanced by Mark Winterbottom and Brooke Rutherford

I tried to test deployment locally like you do in episode 144.Update Django settings, but i have problems there (it stuck in a loop).

[image]

I tried to find what's went wrong but can't find it out.
There is my repo: https://github.com/oliwier93/recipe-app-api

How to pass by this issue?